# python list sort key function choice

Tags: python, sorting, key

I have a list of objects and would like to sort them according to the return value of an instance function. There are two ways to do them

```
from operator import methodcaller

l.sort(key=lambda x:x.f())
l.sort(key=methodcaller('f'))
```

Is one way betther than the other? Or it's just a personal preference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`methodcaller('f')` is *faster*, because it can do both the attribute lookup and the method call in C code.

The lambda adds the following extra overhead:

- Calling the `lambda` has to step out of the `sort()` C loop back into Python code. This requires a new frame object with associated data.
- Looking up the method attribute is a Python opcode with more overhead than the direct equivalent in C.
- Calling the method from a Python frame next has to push that frame on the Python call stack again. C code has a stack too, but this is far lighter.
- Returning from the called method goes back to the Python frame, popping that from the stack, and after which the `lambda` returns, causing the function frame to be destroyed again (which is more work still).

You can measure the difference:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('m("")', 'm = lambda s: s.lower()', number=10**7)
1.2575681940070353
>>> timeit('m("")', 'from operator import methodcaller; m = methodcaller("lower")', number=10**7)
1.061251598992385
```

So on 7 million calls to `str.lower()` on an empty string, a `methodcaller()` is about 16% faster.

Now, if all your data is of the *exact same type*, where `object.f` would *always* bind to the same method, then you can just use the unbound method:

```
l.sort(key=SharedType.f)
```

That saves you having to look it up on each of the instances.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way, if all elements of `l` are garunteed to be of the same type , is for

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def f(self):
        ...
```

you can do

```
l.sort(key=X.f)
```

Comment: This only works if all the objects in the list are the same type. If they are, say, subclasses of a base class, with each subclass having overridden `f`, then this certainly won't work.

Answer (score 1):

They are completly equivalent but `methodcaller` might be a bit faster:

```
class Fun(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def f(self):
        return self.value

import random
from operator import methodcaller

l = [Fun(random.random()) for _ in range(10000)]

assert sorted(l, key=lambda x:x.f()) == sorted(l, key=methodcaller('f'))

%timeit sorted(l, key=lambda x:x.f())     # 100 loops, best of 3: 8.4 ms per loop
%timeit sorted(l, key=methodcaller('f'))  # 100 loops, best of 3: 7.5 ms per loop
```

As pointed out by @PatrickHaugh you might also just use `class.f` as key function which is *even faster* but as @MartijnPieters said this only works if all objects are of the type `class`:

```
%timeit sorted(l, key=Fun.f)              # 100 loops, best of 3: 6.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: A `methodcaller` is *always* faster than a lambda for this case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In almost all cases `methodcaller` is faster. But creating a `lambda` is faster than creating a `methodcaller` (at least on my computer) and for very short lists 2-5 items the lambda is faster/comparable.

Comment: It would, at most, be too close to call, because with 2-5 items other 'noise' would drown out the difference.

Comment: okay but "too close to call" is just admitting that it's not "always faster", right?

Comment: No, it *is* faster, but you can't measure this because on a multi-tasking machine you can't prevent the OS from doing some disk I/O or scheduling in between the instructions; those small 'distractions' make it impossible to get an accurate reading on so little data.

Comment: Speed differences are *accumulative*. They may not matter when you have but 2 or 3 items to sort, but that's why you repeat the operation a large number of times, to amplify that difference so you can get a proper answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm aware of those noise factors, that's why I measured `l = [Fun(0.5427351046967868), Fun(0.31228694481559327), Fun(0.3473029240225134)]

%timeit [sorted(l, key=lambda x:x.f()) for _ in range(1000)]
%timeit [sorted(l, key=methodcaller('f')) for _ in range(1000)]` instead of just a single sorted. And it's constantly faster with `lambda`. You are definitly right about the asymptotic behaviour but constant factors are also important.

Comment: But now you are creating 1000 lists. The time needed to allocate memory for all those is definitely going to drown out any differences between the two approaches, which each only get called 3 times per sort. You want to amplify *just* the calls to the lambda or the methodcaller, not also measure list comprehension looping, creation times for the lambda and methodcaller (each created 1000 times per test) and calls to `sorted()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Did you run the timeits? In 20 test runs lambda won 20 times and I highly doubt that any of your mentioned factors actually differ between lambda and methodcaller, except of course the creation of the lambda function or the methodcaller object which is exactly the point I'm trying to make. You can also put them in a loop if you want to neglect list-creation overheads. But still lamda wins.

Comment: I already included a time trial in my answer. `sorted()` calls the key on each value exactly once. I'm not sure *what* point you are trying to make, are you saying creating the lambda is faster than creating the methodcaller? Yes, because it can just load the bytecode constant that is already compiled. But that doesn't mean a thing when you create those just once before the sort then call the resulting object 1000 times.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the point: _Creating_ a methodcaller object is slower than creating a lambda function which means the constant factor of sorting with methodcaller is bigger (neither the OP no any answerer here created the key beforehand so that's a definite cost in the sorting). That _calling_ the `methodcaller` object is faster than calling the `lambda` is what my answer already points out. I'm just disputing your "A methodcaller is **always** faster than a lambda for **this case**." statement. However I already deleted my statement that probably triggered this conversaton from the post.

Comment: Why? Constant factors are an important contributor if one talks about performance. I don't understand why you "fight" me on this point.

Comment: You asked a question earlier: *okay but "too close to call" is just admitting that it's not "always faster", right?* I disagreed and we discussed, I was trying to figure out where the misconception came from. You have to be explicit about your assumptions and what you include and exclude in your speed assessment. Including object creation timings is a common error when creating time trials, and you could have stated, up front, that you feel that those should count you created ambiguity. I happen to disagree, but I'm not 'fighting' here. I'm just discussing.

Comment: okay, I understand but already my first comment explicitly stated the **creation** of the key functions, so it felt we're running in circles. The object creation time is important in some contexts, say you call the sorting function 1000 of times with small lists then a lambda could actually speed it up (or reusing the methodcaller object). In the example the OP mentioned he would create one object per sort so it may be far fetched but definitly applies here. But yeah, in the end this is probably just some useless fact given that it's less than 10% difference.